# Medir o tempo de execução de uma função

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime

Como posso medir o tempo de execução de uma função em Python?

Em C#, consigo utilizar a classe [**`Stopwatch`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) dessa maneira

```cs
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
AlgumaFuncao();
sw.Stop();

WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você pode usar [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time):

```
import time

inicio = time.time()
funcao()
fim = time.time()
print(fim - inicio)
```

Answer (score 9):

Basicamente você deve pegar os tempos de início e final do teste e então verificar a diferença.

São várias as opções de como pegar um tempo em Python, como por exemplo as funções do módulo [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), que pega tanto valores reais (hora do sistema), como valores relativos (contadores entre uma chamada e outra da função).

Entretanto a partir do Python 2.3 existe o módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), que de acordo com a documentação:

> This module provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code. It has both a Command-Line Interface as well as a callable one. It avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times.

Em tradução livre:

> Esse módulo provê uma maneira simples de medir pequenos trechos de código Python. Ele tem tanto uma interface via comando de linha como uma resgatável. Ela evita uma série de pegadinhas comuns na medição de tempos de execução.

A função a ser usada desse módulo seria a default_timer(), que de acordo com a documentação:

> Define a default timer, in a platform-specific manner. On Windows, time.clock() has microsecond granularity, but time.time()‘s granularity is 1/60th of a second. On Unix, time.clock() has 1/100th of a second granularity, and time.time() is much more precise. On either platform, default_timer() measures wall clock time, not the CPU time. This means that other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing.

Em tradução livre:

> Define um timer padrão, e específico para a plataforma. No Windows, time.clock() tem granularidade de microsegundos, mas a granulariade de time.time() é de 1/60 segundos. No Unix, time.clock() tem uma granularidade de 1/100 segundos, e o time.time() é muito mais preciso. Em qualquer plataforma, default_timer() mede o tempo real, não o tempo de CPU. Isso significa que outros processos rodando no mesmo computador podem interferir nessa medição de tempo.

Até o Python 2, o `timeit.default_timer()` escolhe o que for melhor para o seu sistema operacional dentre o `time.time()` e o `time.clock()`, no Python 3 ele sempre escolhe o `time.perf_counter()`. Portanto, o `timeit.default_timer()` é a opção mais robusta dentre as versões de Python e sistemas operacionais.

Exemplo de como ficaria a medição usando esse módulo:

```
import time
import timeit


def alguma_funcao():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        time.sleep(1)

inicio = timeit.default_timer()
alguma_funcao()
fim = timeit.default_timer()
print ('duracao: %f' % (fim - inicio))
```

Um exemplo de um possível resultado da execução acima:

> duracao: 4.002503

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a função timeit do módulo timeit é mais simples e robusta para se medir o tempo de execução de algum código em Python. Com ela, você não precisa calcular o delta de execução tendo em vista que é justamente esse o valor que ela retorna. Além disso, você consegue controlar quantas execuções do código você vai fazer, o que te permite calcular uma média do tempo de execução.

Segue um exemplo de três funções que geram uma lista de 10 inteiros:

```
def f1():
    return list(range(10))

def f2():
    return [x for x in range(10)]

def f3():
    lst = []
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        lst.append(i)
        i += 1
    return lst
```

O cálculo:

```
from timeit import timeit

v1 = timeit('f1()', 'from __main__ import f1', number=100)
v2 = timeit('f2()', 'from __main__ import f2', number=100)
v3 = timeit('f3()', 'from __main__ import f3', number=100)

print(v1, v2, v3)
```