# Tempo datetime.datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime

Estou fazendo um script em que meço a performance de uma consulta em uma banco de dados. O código é o seguinte:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()

//CONSULTA AQUI

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print "Time taken: %s"%(end - start, )
```

O programa retornou o seguinte resultado na primeira consulta: Time taken: 0:00:00.000593
Em uma outra consulta apresentou o seguinte resultado: Time taken: 0:00:31.833141

Os dois resultados estão sendo dados em milissegundos ou em segundos?

Comment: Relacionada (ou duplicada?): [Medir o tempo de execução de uma função](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97364/18246)

Comment: não entendi a pergunta @jbueno

Comment: A primeira consulta levou menos de 1 milésimo de segundo, a segunda levou 31 segundos e alguns milésimos. Depois do ponto são os milésimos.

Comment: Obrigada, pessoal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somente o `segundo(Time taken: 0:00:31.833141)` está em segundos. O primeiro está em milissegundos.

Comment: Então no caso, posso afirmar que o primeiro é 0.000593 segundo, certo?

Comment: Exato, porém seria melhor você dizer que foi menos que um milésimo de segundo do que falar que foi 0.000593 segundos

Comment: Ah, mas é porque estou trabalhando com dados estatísticos em planilha e preciso colocar o número preciso, entendeu?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Boa sorte no projeto!

Comment: Obrigada, projeto de TCC :)